# How to call javascript function from java?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I have a native android library, Which expects a java function which works as an event. But in my nativescript plugin, I want to pass javascript function to the library so that library events are fired in javascript runtime.

Comment: Can you please share more info, may be the Java code snippet to understand whether your Java method expects an interface / callable etc.,

Comment: Yes, It expects an interface with 2 methods defined inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Java method expects an interface for callback functions, it's already covered in the [NativeScript docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/binding-generator/extend-class-interface#interfaces).

**Java**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
    }
});
```

**JavaScript**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener({
    onClick: function() {
        // Perform action on click
    }
}));
```